# Nodemailer crashes when sending multiple attachments

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I am using `nodemailer` and I need to send multiple attachments. The problem seems to appear when the overall weight of all attachments "is too big". Here is my code:

```
const mailOptions = {
     ...,
     attachments: [{
           filename: 'image1.png',
           content: 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGAAAABgAQMAAADYVuV7AAAABlBMVEUAAAAAAAClZ7nPAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAB9JREFUeAFjgIJRwP+BZM4oh/8/GHygIYd8h45yRgEAaHBnmaA4EHkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=',
           encoding: 'base64'
        },
        {   
            filename: 'image2.png',
            content: 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGAAAABgAQMAAADYVuV7AAAABlBMVEUAAAAAAAClZ7nPAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAB9JREFUeAFjgIJRwP+BZM4oh/8/GHygIYd8h45yRgEAaHBnmaA4EHkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=',
            encoding: 'base64'
        },{ 
            filename: 'image3.png',
            content: 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGAAAABgAQMAAADYVuV7AAAABlBMVEUAAAAAAAClZ7nPAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAB9JREFUeAFjgIJRwP+BZM4oh/8/GHygIYd8h45yRgEAaHBnmaA4EHkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=',
            encoding: 'base64'
    }]
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Connection closed
at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (...\node_modules\nodemailer-smtp-transport\lib\smtp-transport.js:117:29)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
at SMTPConnection.emit (events.js:189:13)
at SMTPConnection._destroy (...\node_modules\smtp-connection\lib\smtp-connection.js:593:10)
at SMTPConnection._onEnd (...\node_modules\smtp-connection\lib\smtp-connection.js:573:10)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1125:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is regarding `size`? because somehow your `Connection` is getting closed before completion of the function!

Comment: I assume that base on the fact that it works when I send just 2 attachments, however when I change attachments to bigger ones, it crashes even with 2 attachments.